# Tex: How do I move chapter headings up in mini table of content of parts

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}[0em] % Indenting
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{}  
{\color{ocre}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indenting
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that exhibits your problem.

Comment: You may download the entire thing from here. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/the-legrand-orange-book-template-english/jtctyfmnpppc

Comment: I have no intention of downloading anything. It is up to you to provide an MWE

Answer (score 1):

One note of warning: I am not at all convinced by the overall quality of the code of the template in question. I would not recommend using it.

---

The template you want to use is obviously a custom template that essentially stores all the stuff from the preamble in the file `structure.tex` which is then included in the main TeX file using `\input{structure}`. In the file `structure.tex` you need to look for the following code:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
```

This essentially overwrites the `\@part` macro as defined in the `book` class on which the whole template is based. The `\@part` macro does the formatting of part titles.

Now, you said that you want to shift the mini toc upwards if I understand you correctly. As you can see from the code, the `tikz` package is used to paint the ocre color onto the page and also to place the mini toc.

More concretely, the mini toc is typeset with this part of the code:

```
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
```

The mini toc is placed inside a box that is 8.5cm wide and which again is placed inside a Ti*k*Z node whose lower right corner is placed 1cm to the left of the right margin of the page and 1cm above the bottom margin of the page.

You can therefore, for example write a higher number for the y coordinate (the one which was originally set to be `-\paperheight+1cm`), so for example you could write `-\paperheight+10cm` which would mean "10cm from the bottom margin of the page" or you write `15cm` which would mean "15cm from the top margin of the page".

Comment: +1 for the warning at the start :)